# Database: Filtering XML based records by tag values

Tags: mysql, xml, database-design, nosql

I had a requirement where we have a lot (~200,000) of records, each having 200 fields. The data will never be altered after the initial insert queries, but there will be a lot of fetching based on certain filters (ex: get all the records with field_3 = 42 and field_42 = 3).

We solved this using a relational table, having one column for each of the 200 fields. It was all working fine, until...

We got a similar requirement for XML based records. The distinction being, that while the records earlier could contain only 200 fields, the new XML records can contain any number of tags from a pool of around 1000 tags. Also, most of the records will be quite sparse (with only tens of tags).
My question is, how can we extend the earlier solution to these XML based records?
Do we need to look at NoSQL databases? Will they handle the original non-XML records well?

Some points:

- The records in one *table* will be immutable. We just need to filter the records based on some criteria.
- All the queries will fetch the whole record (`SELECT * FROM`).

Comment: Will you need to search on each of the 1000 tags?  Do you ever search on multiple tags?  "based on some criteria" -- elaborate.

Comment: Search will be on 'some' of the tags (mostly 3-4), never on all 1000. But these 'some' tags are not fixed. I mean, we can get a request to search for any combination of those 1000 tags.

Answer (score 0):

"any combination" ==  Most queries will have to search the entire table.  Are a *few* of the tags used *most* of the time?  If so, index them but throw the rest into a JSON column.  (XML is really yucky to deal with.)

[*EAV discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav)